# How can I Embed text inside image?

Tags: android

[image]

I want to display a custom text (mainly person info) inside an image like it's shown above. How can I do it in android? For example, I have a known size of this image (it differs from device to device) and want to display it with the different text size inside it in the special place.

Comment: `like it's shown below` ?

Comment: i posted image, could u look again

Comment: Added an answer. Please check it and approve if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, `RelativeLayout`.
Make your `ImageView` be `match_parent` and use some container for your text lines in bottom of parent `RelativeLayout`.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="#92fffaaa"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Some test text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this (adjust dimensions as your requirement)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#64000000"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Sub Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar previously.

- Use `Framelayout`.
- Add `ImageView` in frame layout with `match_parent` constraints.
- Add `LinearLayout` having `background="#80000000"` and `layout_gravity="center"` in `FrameLayout` which contains your two TextViews.

Let me know in case this does not work.